I cant Run my flutter app after intergrating firebase to my project
I can see the following as logs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\adith\Desktop\fltr\firebase_project\android\app\build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1]

Can someone help me with this?

Post your build.gradle file, so that people can comment, also see how to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

The error says "[id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found". Did you add com.google.gms.google-servies in your android/app/build.gradle file?

Check if you have added these lines:

Add google-services.json file



Add services plugin in build.gradle and settings.gradle

android/app/build.gradle

android/settings.gradle


Please add Google Services file in Android and iOS.
